# Area under Dirac Delta function

Tags: signal

What is the difference of the area calculation for the Dirac delta function when using different limits of integration?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)dx = 1$$

but

$$\int_{-\infty}^{t}\delta(x)dx = u(t)$$

Comment: What is the limit of u(t) as t goes to infinity? (Alternatively, what is the value of u(t) for any t > 0? and is +infinity > 0?)

Comment: isnt limit of u(t) as t goes to infinity 1?

Comment: @Fawaz, no, u(t) is simply 1, t>=0, by definition.  No need to invoke limits

Comment: @ScottSeidman, "infinity" isn't a real number, it is only something we can approach as a limit. (e.g. whenever we talk about "infinity" we are actually using a shorthand to  talk about a limit) However, I do admit I'm only doing "engineering math" here. If OP wants a mathematician's answer, they should go to math.SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When integrating to only \$t\$ there are two cases: if \$t < 0\$ then the integral is \$0\$, if \$t \geq 0\$ then the integral is \$1\$:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{t}\delta(x)dx = \begin{cases} 0\text{, }t < 0 \\ 1\text{, }t \geq 0\end{cases}$$

But this is just another way of writing the unit step function \$u(t)\$ so

$$\int_{-\infty}^{t}\delta(x)dx = u(t)$$

Since $$\lim_{t \to \infty} u(t) = 1$$ then it is also true that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)dx = 1$$

Answer (score 4):

There's no contradiction.

$$
\begin{matrix}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\ \delta(t) \mathrm{d}t &=& \lim_{\tau\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\tau\ \delta(t) \mathrm{d}t\\
 &=& \lim_{\tau\to\infty}u(\tau)\\
 &=& 1
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Is this a proper limit problem?  The integral of delta(t) is u(t), so the integral is u(infinity)-u(-infinity) = 1-0 =1.  I haven't seen this handled as limits.